# Template errors not caught during build in Angular library

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-packagr

I have an Angular 15 project with several libraries and applications that consume those libraries. When I build any of the libraries separately with ng-packagr no template errors are thrown. Only when I do an aot build of an application that consumes those libraries are template errors caught.

I tried changing settings in each library tsconfig to:
angularCompilerOptions

- "strictTemplates": true
- "enableIvy": true

Only "strict": true has an effect but that is too strict

Also tried adding --aot but since Angular 9 aot should be default

My question is if this is normal? I would like to catch template errors when I build a library by itself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.